# entity createdatabase ldf log file name change default how to

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, visual-web-developer-2010

Visual Web Developer. Entity data sources model.  I have it creating the new database fine.  Example
creates SAMPLE1.MDF  and SAMPLE1.LDF
When I run my app, it creates another SAMPLE1_LOG.lDF file.

When I run createdatabase, is there a place I can specify the _LOG.ldf for the log file?  SQL 2008 r2.

It messes up when I run the DeleteDatabase functions... 2 log files...

How come it does not create the file SAMPLE1_Log.ldf to start with, if that is what it is looking for...

Thank you for your time,
Frank

```
     // database or initial catalog produce same results...

     // strip the .mdf off of newfile and see what happens?
     // nope. this did not do anything... still not create the ldf file correctly!!!
     // sample1.mdf, sample1.ldf... but when run, it creates sample1_log.LDF... 
     newfile = newfile.Substring(0, newfile.Length - 4);

     String mfile = "Initial Catalog=" + newfile + ";data source=";


     String connectionString = FT_EntityDataSource.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionString().Replace("data source=", mfile);

     // String mexclude = @"attachdbfilename=" + "|" + "DataDirectory" + "|" + @"\" + newfile + ";";
     // nope. must have attach to create the file in the app_data, otherwise if goes to documents & setting, etc sqlexpress.
     // connectionString = connectionString.Replace(mexclude, "");

     Labeldebug2.Text = connectionString;

     using (FTMAIN_DataEntities1 context = new FTMAIN_DataEntities1(connectionString))
     {
        //            try
        //            {
        if (context.DatabaseExists())
        {
           Buttoncreatedb.Enabled = false;
           box.Checked = true;
           boxcreatedate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
           Session["zusermdf"] = Session["zusermdfsave"];
           return;
           // Make sure the database instance is closed.
           // context.DeleteDatabase();
           // i have entire diff section for deletedatabase.. not here. 
        }
        // View the database creation script.
        // Labeldebug.Text = Labeldebug.Text + "  script ==> " + context.CreateDatabaseScript().ToString().Trim();
        // Console.WriteLine(context.CreateDatabaseScript());
        // Create the new database instance based on the storage (SSDL) section 
        // of the .edmx file.

        context.CreateDatabaseScript();
        context.CreateDatabase();
    }
```

took out all the try, catch so i can see anything that might happen...

==========================================================================

Rough code while working out the kinks..

connection string it creates

metadata=res://*/FT_EDS1.csdl|res://*/FT_EDS1.ssdl|res://*/FT_EDS1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Initial Catalog=data_bac100;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\data_bac100.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

in this example, the file to create is "data_bac100.mdf".
It creates the data_bac100.mdf and data_bac100.ldf

when I actually use this file and tables to run, it auto-creates data_bac100_log.LDF

1) was trying just not to create the ldf, so when the system runs, it just creates the single one off the bat...

2) the Initial Catalog, and/or Database keywords are ONLY added to the connection string to run the createdatabase().. the regular connection strings created in web config only have attachdbfilename stuff, and works fine.

I have 1 connection string for unlimited databases, with the main database in the web.config..  I use a initialize section based on the user roles, whether visitor, member, admin, anonymous, or not authenticated... which sets the database correctly with a expression builder, and function to parse the connection string with the correct values for the database to operate on.    This all runs good.

The entity framework automatically generates the script.  I have tried with and without the .mdf extensions, makes no difference...  thought maybe there is a setup somewhere that holds naming conventions for ldf files...

Eventually all of this will be for naught when start trying to deploy where not using APP_Data folder anyways...

Here is an example of connection string created when running application
metadata=res://*/FT_EDS1.csdl|res://*/FT_EDS1.ssdl|res://*/FT_EDS1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TDSLLC_Data.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

in this case, use the TDSLLCData.mdf file...

04/01/2012... followup...
Entity Framework

feature 
Log files created by the ObjectContext.CreateDatabase method

change
When the CreateDatabase method is called either directly or by using Code First with the SqlClient provider and an AttachDBFilename value in the connection string, it creates a log file named filename_log.ldf instead of filename.ldf (where filename is the name of the file specified by the AttachDBFilename value).

impact.
This change improves debugging by providing a log file named according to SQL Server specifications. It should have no unexpected side effects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx

I am on a Windows XP with .net 4 (not .net 4.5)... will hunt some more.. but looks like a issue that cannot be changed.

4/1/2012, 4:30... 
ok, more hunting and searching and some of the inconsistancies I have experienced with createdatabase and databaseexists...  so .net 4.5 is supposed to add the _log.ldf, and not just .ldf files, so they must have addressed this for some reason....

found others with same issues, but different server....
MySQL has a connector for EF4, the current version is 6.3.5 and its main functionalities are working fine but it still has issues with a few methods, e.g.
•System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
•System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DatabaseExists()
which makes it difficult to fully use the model-first approach. It's possible by manually editing the MySQL script (available with the CreateDatabaseScript method). The MySQL team doesn't seem eager to solve those bugs, I'm not sure what the commitment level actually is from their part but it certainly is lower than it once was.
That being said, the same methods fail with SQL CE too (they are not implemented, and I don't see the MS team as likely to tackle that soon).

---

Ran out of space below... it just becomes a problem when create a database, and it does not create the _log.ldf file, but just the ldf file, then use the database, and it creates a _log.ldf file... now you have 2 ldf files.. one becomes invalid..  Then when done with the database, delete it, then try to create a new, and a ldf exists, it will not work....

---

it turns out this is just the way it is with EF4, and they changed with EF4.5 beta to create the _log.ldf file to match what is created when the database is used.

thanks for time.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this "mdf attachment" feature myself and I don't know much about it, but according to the [xcopy deployment documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165716.aspx), you should not create a log file yourself because it will be automatically created when you attach the mdf. The docs also mention naming and say that the new log filename ends in _log.ldf. In other words, this behaviour appears to be by design and you can't change it.

Perhaps a more important question is, why do you care what the log file is called? Does it actually cause any problems for your application? If so, you should give details of that problem and see if someone has a solution.

Comment: It doesnt really matter, because now working on executing a sql script against a empty database to create the schema, since my hosting provider requires the database shell be created in the Web Panel manually... then have the program execute the script against the database when create a new database for a customer. ------ When you create the database with the objectcontext.createdatabase, it does NOT create a _LOG.LDF file... it simply creates the .ldf extension..  this is in EF4.  I see the beta EF4.5 changed this to create the _LOG.LDF file.  Not the case with EF4.